# Tor keeps timing out when I try to access websites

Tags: configuration, onion-services

I am having a bit of trouble getting this to work. Can anyone help me resolve this problem?

```
3/17/2017 17:41:53 PM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/17/2017 17:41:53 PM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/17/2017 17:41:53 PM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/17/2017 17:41:53 PM.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/17/2017 17:41:53 PM.400 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.1" 
3/17/2017 17:41:54 PM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
3/17/2017 17:41:54 PM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
3/17/2017 17:41:54 PM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
3/17/2017 17:41:54 PM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
3/17/2017 17:41:54 PM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
3/17/2017 17:41:55 PM.200 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
3/17/2017 17:41:55 PM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 40%: Loading authority key certs 
3/17/2017 17:41:55 PM.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 45%: Asking for relay descriptors 
3/17/2017 17:41:55 PM.800 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We need more microdescriptors: we have 0/7354, and can only build 0% of likely paths. (We have 0% of guards bw, 0% of midpoint bw, and 0% of exit bw = 0% of path bw.) 
3/17/2017 17:41:56 PM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 50%: Loading relay descriptors 
3/17/2017 17:41:58 PM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 56%: Loading relay descriptors 
3/17/2017 17:41:58 PM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 64%: Loading relay descriptors 
3/17/2017 17:41:58 PM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 73%: Loading relay descriptors 
3/17/2017 17:41:58 PM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network 
3/17/2017 17:41:59 PM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit 
3/17/2017 17:41:59 PM.700 [NOTICE] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working. 
3/17/2017 17:41:59 PM.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100%: Done 
3/17/2017 17:42:01 PM.000 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
3/17/2017 17:42:01 PM.100 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
3/17/2017 17:51:14 PM.300 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:80. Giving up. (waiting for rendezvous desc)
```

Comment: Why do you think it has something to do why onion sites?

Answer (score -1):

It's OK for a case when you have a ClientOnly mode, because it highly depends on your connection to get an actual HiddenService rendezvous points. If you have to use a client only mode - it's quite an often problem and you just have to wait, it will come up, but how quick - it's truly connection-dependent. If you have the chance - then make it a middle relay **with** reachable ORPort and DirPort - it will work fine after 2-3 minutes after bootup, timings verified even on 3G connection.

Comment: No, this is not correct and is useless advice that will not fix the error the user is experiencing. Stop trying to harm users, Alexey and stop trying to entrap them into contacting you directly.